# U-SQL extractor. Can we retrieve the ignored lines when using silent option?

Tags: azure, u-sql

I am using the silent option when using U-sql extractors. Is there a way to retreive and monitor the ignored lines?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot get the ignored lines. If you want to capture them, you would have to write a custom extractor that returns the ignored lines using one of the two approaches:

1. Use the `DiagnosticStream` object to output it into a diagnostic file. Note that you will have to turn diagnostic on when running the script to get the diagnostic result.
2. Add an extra column to your output of type `byte[]` that will capture your ignored line and set all other column values to `null`.